# dispatch action from form submit

Tags: reactjs, redux

In a modal, When I dispatch an action with form data, when I try and dispatch an action to close the model I get an error

**Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`**

Here is my submit function:

```
   constructor() {
       super();
         this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }


submitForm(){

let title = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).selectedOptions[0].label;
let achievementHour = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.hourSelect).selectedOptions[0].label
let achievementMin = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.minSelect).selectedOptions[0].label
let timeString = achievementHour + ":" + achievementMin;

this.props.onChange(this.props.dayId, title, timeString)
this.props.onClose()
```

}

My modal reducer should then close my modal:

```
import AddEnjoymentModal from './AddEnjoymentModal.js';
import AddAchievementModal from './AddAchievementModal.js';

const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  'ADD_ENJOYMENT': AddEnjoymentModal,
  'ADD_ACHIEVEMENT': AddAchievementModal

  /* other modals */
}

const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps }) => {
  if (!modalType) {
    return <span /> 
  }

  const SpecificModal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[modalType]
  return <SpecificModal {...modalProps} />
}

export default connect(
  state => state.modal
)(ModalRoot)
```

My action to hide the modal:

```
export const hideModal = (modalProps) => ({ type: types.HIDE_MODAL, ...modalProps })
```

I open the modal using:

```
this.props.showAchievement({
   type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
  modalType: 'ADD_ACHIEVEMENT',
  modalProps: {
  dayId: this.props.day.id,
  onChange: this.props.addAchievement,
  onClose: this.props.hideModal
}
})
```

Model render:

```
   return (
         <span >
          <ModalWrapper
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeModal}
            style={this.props.customStyles}
            contentLabel="Modal" >

          <h2>Add Achievement</h2>

             <select name="title" ref="title">
               {options.map((option) => (
                      <option value={option.value}>{option.label} </option>
                ))}
            </select>


            <select name="hourSelect" ref="hourSelect">
               {hourSelect.map((option) => (
                      <option value={option.value}>{option.label} </option>
                ))}
            </select>


            <select name="minSelect" ref="minSelect">
               {minSelect.map((option) => (
                      <option value={option.value}>{option.label} </option>
                ))}
            </select>




            <a href="#" onClick={this.submitForm} >Submit</a>

          </ModalWrapper>
      </span>
    )
```

Comment: Can you paste your modal's `render` function?  The likely cause is that you're accidentally calling `submitForm`, instead of passing a reference to it.  Also, as a side note: your use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` and string refs are outdated, and you should probably try to update your code to use callback refs instead, like : `<div ref={ (divElement => this.theDiv = divElement }</div>`.  Finally, you might also want to consider using "controlled inputs" instead of accessing the DOM elements directly.

Comment: Thanks ive updated my answer

Comment: How would I use controlled inputs with my modal and reduce?

Comment: Hmm. As far as your original question goes: the `render` method _looks_ okay, and it doesn't seem like you're accidentally calling `setState` or similar inside of rendering.  For controlled inputs, see [Gosha Arinich's blog posts about using forms in React](https://goshakkk.name/on-forms-react/), as well as the [other tutorials on React and forms](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-forms.md) in my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).